# how close spring integration tcp connection after response

Tags: java, tcp, spring-integration

I writing a tcp server with 0 byte terminator.
The setup is working for both direction, but the server dont close the connection after send the response:

Setup:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="MyServerConnectionFactory"
                           type="server"
                           port="8083"
                           serializer="MyConnectionSerializeDeserialize"
                           deserializer="MyConnectionSerializeDeserialize"
                           />
<bean id="MyConnectionSerializeDeserialize"     class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer">
        <constructor-arg type="byte" value="0" />
        <property name="maxMessageSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>


<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="MyGateway"
                        connection-factory="MyServerConnectionFactory"
                        request-channel="MyIncomingServerChannel"
                        error-channel="errorChannel"/>

<int:channel id="MyIncomingServerChannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="MyIncomingServerChannel"
                   ref="MyService"
                   method="process"/>

<bean id="MyService"
  class="mypackage.MyService"/>
```

Code in the MyService:

```
   public byte[] process(byte[] input) {
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
        // process the stream
    ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outstream);
    pw.print("Ok");
    pw.flush();
    return outstream.toByteArray();
}
```

How can I tell the framework to close the connection after send back the response?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

It's usually the responsibility of the client to close the socket after it receives the response but if you set `single-use="true"` on the connection factory, the socket will be closed (normally - FIN) after the response is sent.

Comment: Yes, but the client is a php and its don't close the connection after received a 0x00 char, and its use some socket_recv() function what is lack of config.. its just wait forever..